# How to check other game board diagonal

Tags: c++

I have working code that works and can check if a player has won (when the diagonal is from the upper right to lower left). However, I can't seem to figure out how to make it work for upper left to lower right diagonal.

This code works:(upper right to lower left diagonal)

```
for(int x = boardSize, y = 0; x > 0; x--, y++){
    playerCount = 0;
    for(int row = y, col = 0; col < x; row++, col++){
        if(gameBoard[col][row] == '_')
            playerCount = 0;
        if(gameBoard[col][row] == playerSign) 
            playerCount++;
        if(playerCount == winningSize)
            return true;
    }
}
```

How would I need to change the code to make it work for the other diagonal (upper left to lower right). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work for the second diagonal:

```
for (int y = 0, x = size-1; y < size; y++, x--){
        if (board[y][x] == ' '){
            count = 0;
        }else if (board[y][x] == p){
            count++;
            if (count == s)
                return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it actually works for the second diagonal!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is overly-complicated. To test the diagonal from (0,0) to (size-1,size-1), inclusive:

```
for (int z = 0; z < size; ++z) {
  if (board[z][z] == ' ')
    count = 0;
  else if (board[z][z] == p) {
    ++count;
    if (count == s)
      return true;
  }
}
```

Note that you don't need a nested (2-dimensional) loop to scan a diagonal, which is essentially a 1-dimensional thing.